# Set Cronjob to Run Every 5 Minutes From 9:30am to 4:00pm

Tags: linux, unix, cron

I need to set a cronjob to run a bash script every 5 minutes, starting at 9:30am until 4:00pm.

I have the following but, it's not quite right...

Cronjob:

```
*/5 9-16 * * * /path/to/directory/job.sh > /path/to/log/file/job.log 2>&1
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you have there is a line that will run the command every five minutes between `09:00` and `16:55` (all ranges here are inclusive).

What you're trying to achieve can be done relatively simply with three *separate* `crontab` lines:

```
30-59/5 9     * * * /path/to/directory/job.sh > /path/to/log/file/job.log 2>&1
*/5     10-15 * * * /path/to/directory/job.sh > /path/to/log/file/job.log 2>&1
0       16    * * * /path/to/directory/job.sh > /path/to/log/file/job.log 2>&1
```

The first handles the case between `09:30` and `09:55`, the second every five minutes between `10:00` and `15:55`, and the final one the single job at `16:00`.

Answer (score 5):

Cron doesn't have a syntax for expressing that directly, so you'll need 3 separate lines: one for 9:30-9:55, one for 10:00-15:55, and one for 16:00.

I *think* this is correct:

```
30-55/5 9     * * * <command>
*/5     10-15 * * * <command>
0       16    * * * <command>
```